# java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server while submitting DistCp job

Tags: java, hadoop, distcp

When i submit distcp job to copy files from insecured hadoop cluster to secured(kerberized) cluster, I encountered an error below:

```
2017-08-28 17:42:09,526 FATAL [IPC Server handler 0 on 42131] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1503655816205_0288_m_000000_0 - exited : java.io.IOException: File copy failed: webhdfs://source/path --> webhdfs://target/path
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying webhdfs://source/path to webhdfs://target/path
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:280)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3479)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3462)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyBytes(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
    ... 11 more

2017-08-28 17:42:09,526 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 42131] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1503655816205_0288_m_000000_0: Error: java.io.IOException: File copy failed: webhdfs://source/path --> webhdfs://target/path
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying webhdfs://source/path to webhdfs://target/path
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.copyFileWithRetry(CopyMapper.java:280)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3479)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3462)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyBytes(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.copyToFile(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doCopy(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand.doExecute(RetriableFileCopyCommand.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.RetriableCommand.execute(RetriableCommand.java:87)
    ... 11 more
```

As `Error writing request body to server` message is too broad, I can't get clue what to dig in. Any hint here?

FYI, I tested mapreduce pi example on secured cluster and it works fine.